# Skater obfuscator whole .NET app protection is too slow

Tags: .net, obfuscation

I just installed Skater Demo yesterday.  I chose the middling option and added strings to it. 
On a 4.5 gig exe it ran for one and half hour.  Just for curiosity, I started a 10gig DLL and it has been running for over 15 minutes. What am I doing wrong? Or is it really just that slow?

Comment: 4.5GB exe?  10GB dll?  what?

Comment: You're complaining that a complex tool takes over 15 minutes to run on a 10Gb data set?  Computers are fast, but not infinitely fast. [I'm a little stunned that you can have a "10Gigbyte DLL".  Are you sure you have the units right?

Answer (score 1):

The obfuscation is a slow process in general. For your case scenario, when you protect such huge assemblies consider to do not encrypt all strings and do not Control Flow protect all methods of your assembly. Applying all such members is increasing your final obfuscated assembly size in several times. Check some important strings and methods only to protect. Also you may consider apply the cryptography for your string encryption since it produces smaller IL code.